# Different shipping cost for postcodes in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I would like to define different shipping costs in Shopware 6 for certain postcodes. I used the rule builder for this but my change is ignored there.

I created two rules.
Once Germany with the condition delivery country Germany
[image: Screenshot]

and the rule Germany island with the condition delivery country Germany and different postcodes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5rYv.png)

I have entered both rules for the shipping method.
[image: Screenshot]

However, if I now want to order with a postal code from the Germany Island rule, the shipping costs for Germany (7.90) always appear and never the 23.90.

Is usually something wrong or what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adapt your rule for the whole of Germany to explicitly not include the postal codes you have set in the island-specific rule. Currently the rule condition for the whole of Germany will also be met for the island locations, hence why the cheaper shipping costs are still available in that case.

So just change the rule accordingly to **exclude** the postal codes from the other rule:

```
  Shipping address: Country > Is one of > [Germany]
  AND
  Shipping address: Postal code > Alphanumeric > Is NONE of > [18565, ...]
OR
  Customer logged in > No
```

Comment: I had already tried that. However, the customer will then be shown before registration that no shipping method is available

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Then just add an or-condition to the rule that is met when a customer is not logged in. Updated the answer accordingly.